# ANTLR4 error: Can't load Hello as lexer or parser

Tags: antlr

So on macOS I have ANTLR4.7 installed and in the directory that antler is installed in I defined my own grammar like so:

```
$ cd cd /usr/local/lib
$ mkdir HelloDir
$ cd HelloDir
$ nano Hello.g4
```

I paste this code in the file:

```
// Define a grammar called Hello
grammar Hello;
r  : 'hello' ID ;         // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ;             // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

And than I saved the file

Then I create the classes:

```
$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Swift Hello.g4 //the files are generated successfully
```

After this I try to see what I created:

```
$ grun Hello r -tree
```

And this is the point when the error message ruins my day:

> Can't load Hello as lexer or parser

The problem might be obvious but I'm new to ANTLR. So what is the problem what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a "." in your CLASSPATH. Usually it will be something like this:

```
.;C:\etc\etc\javalib\antlr-xxx.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct so it suggests that you don't have something installed correctly.  You're likely missing dependencies and in nano there's no convenient way to set them up.    I don't use the swift target, but there are [detailed instructions here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/swift-target.md) on using **XCode** to do your setup, dependencies, and project files.  I'd recommend you try that github resource; it also contains several caveats and tips to get better performance through optimization settings in release mode.